# How to use next.js getInitialProps method with mobx on any page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mobx

I have to use mobx and next.js together in a project. I have looked official documents on github 'with mobx' example. So, I understood that the main idea is server and client stores must be same. And everytime on server connection I should create new store. But I could not have understood that codes in getInıtialProps method. Why we use getInıtialProps 2 times in getInıtialProps method ? And also same codes are used in constructor as well. Could you explain the idea behind it? I could not have found explanatory example. Also, should I use getInıtialProps on every pages or can I use inject and observer instead ?

```
class MyMobxApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps(appContext) {
  // Get or Create the store with `undefined` as initialState
  // This allows you to set a custom default initialState
    const mobxStore = initializeStore()
  // Provide the store to getInitialProps of pages
  appContext.ctx.mobxStore = mobxStore

  let appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)

  return {
    ...appProps,
    initialMobxState: mobxStore,
  }
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
  this.mobxStore = isServer
    ? props.initialMobxState
    : initializeStore(props.initialMobxState)
}

....
```